# Every Sensor Stopped Working

Tags: system-error, sensors, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Recently I have discovered that literally all sensors on my Note 4 suddenly stopped working. This include the proximity sensor as well as the gyroscope sensor and GPS, etc.:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

How can I fix it? Why is it happening? I haven't tried performing a factory reset because I don't want to do that unless it's necessary. Now the screen won't turn off during a call, and the GPS doesn't work in Google maps. I can't even shoot videos in landscape.

This phone is not rooted. Running on Android 5.0.1.

Comment: I'd definitely try the factory reset.

Comment: @MatthewRead I would do it if it is a last resort, but is there anything else I can try to fix it now?

Comment: I don't think so. Back up important data and go for the reset.

Answer (score -1):

the power related to sensors is different from main power in note 4.In this case your sensor power is acting up which is common in note 4.You have to refer it to samsung repair center.
thank you
VRM

Comment: Which will tell you to see if a factory-reset solves the issue before taking in the device, as was already suggested in the comments. Do you have any backing that this is an hardware issue?

Answer (score -1):

turn your phone off, take battery out, hold power button for 20 seconds, let all the power run out, put the battery in, turn your phone on, and see if it works. if it doesnt work. dont waste time and flash stock firmware on it. good luck!